# Need suggestions on audio recording equipment for studying noise in classrooms

Tags: microphone, wireless, speech

Ideally, we would be able to record from 20 or so stationary locations from well-matched microphones with flexibility in how they are set up (stands, on tables, stuck to walls, etc.) and 2-4 headset microphones, all wirelessly with some way to document the spatial location of the microphones. Is this even feasible? Perhaps with the option to have them all begin recording at the exact same time.

Comment: Your assumption that you can use recordings from lavalier microphones to remove these teachers voices from the recordings of classroom noise is fundamentally flawed. You cannot do this. It is not possible. What is the purpose of this project?

Answer (score -1):

An easy way to sync them all: connect all of the microphones to one multitrack recorder (e.g. microphone ->AD converter->computer with DAW software).

Recording the spatial location must be done separately. Measure their positions and make a sketch of the room with the microphones. Use photos. If you want to be really fancy, use photogrammetry or a laser scanner to build a 3D model of the room.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I think I will probably go in this direction. Do you have any suggestions for a microphone capable of connecting to one multitrack recorder and properly suited to record good audio with the acoustics of a classroom in mind?

Comment: I'd think almost any microphone would be usable, but it depends a bit on what you're doing with the recordings. To measure noise levels, you'd have to calibrate them, but that's a one-time effort.

Comment: We want to measure loudness levels, variability in loudness, proportion of noise that is speech and variability in proportion of noise that is speech.

Comment: Audio recordings: To meet our first goal, we will make auditory recordings in 20 active first-grade classrooms.Teachers will wear lavalier microphones for isolating their speech. Recordings will be made during ten randomly select ten 10-minute spans from the 270 minutes first-graders typically spend in their home classroom

Comment: Acoustic analysis: Recordings from lavalier microphones will be used to isolate and remove teachers’ voices from the recordings of classroom noise. For each five-second segment of classroom noise, we will measure RMS amplitude and code the noise as primarily speech, primarily non-speech, or equally speech and non-speech. For each ten-minute recording, we will calculate average and standard deviations of amplitude and proportion of noise that is speech.